# Why is disabling form submission affecting min and max attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm doing some validation on a HTML form using min and max attributes. I also want to prevent form submission if the submit button is clicked once to prevent multiple form submissions before a page is reloaded.

Here's the inline code for disabling the button:

```
<input type="submit" name="name" value="REGISTER" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.form.submit();">
```

Here's the number input field code:

```
<input type="number" name="endNo" placeholder="END" min="5" max="20">
```

If I include the inline JS for the submit button, the min and max validation doesn't work. When removed, it seems to work just fine. Why is this happening and how can I satisfy both conditions, disable the button once clicked while still validating the min and max values for the number input field?

I'm using google chrome.

Comment: something else is wrong, there's no difference for me if I have the onclick code or not

Comment: @JaromandaX Are you certain your browser isn't preventing submission if you try to enter a value greater than 20 in this case? That's the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Chrum lets me submit in either case, but a message does pop up briefly if there's no `this.disabled=false` - however, the end result seems to be the submission goes ahead either way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript

Comment: @JaromandaX I'd like to have the min validation which works perfectly if I don't include the inline JS but I also need a way to disable the submit button once it is clicked once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `submit` method on form element does what it promises, it just submits the form, doesn't do a validation. You can manually do validation with the `checkValidity` method.

```
<input type="submit" name="name" value="REGISTER" 
    onclick="if(this.form.checkValidity()){this.disabled=true;this.form.submit();}">
```

Comment: This solved my dilemma so elegantly. The `checkValidity()` method addresses exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm doing some validation on a HTML form using min and max attributes. I also want to prevent form submission if the submit button is clicked once to prevent multiple form submissions before a page is reloaded.

As you said, you want to prevent **form submission**, so you must point your bullets to the `<form>` tag. When you need to handle the `submit` event, always attack the `<form>`, so let's add an `onsubmit` attribute:

```
<form method="post" action="my-script.php" onsubmit="return something();">
```

Now let's add a little funtion which tells to our `<form>` what to do. In this case let's show the result from the input:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function something() {
    var v = document.getElementById( "endNo" ).value;
    alert( "The value is " + v );
    return false;
}
</script>
```

I added some `id` attribute to the input to be handled by javascript:

```
<input type="number" id="endNo" name="endNo" placeholder="END" min="5" max="20">
```

The submit button only shows the `disabled` event in the `onclick` attribute because `return false` is already being executed on the `<form>` tag:

```
<input type="submit" name="name" value="REGISTER" onclick="this.disabled=true;">
```

The whole tag looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function something() {
    var v = document.getElementById( "endNo" ).value;
    alert( "The value is " + v );
    return false;
}
</script>

<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return something();">
<input type="number" id="endNo" name="endNo" placeholder="END" min="5" max="20">
<input type="submit" name="name" value="REGISTER" onclick="this.disabled=true;">
</form>
```

**See it in action:** https://jsfiddle.net/darioferrer/mfs3adqm/

**Check some similar cases:**

- [On submit form, return false not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480001/on-submit-form-return-false-not-working)
- [onSubmit after checking return false and still submit](http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/131342-onsubmit-after-checking-return-false-still-submit.html)
- [Why does my HTML form still submit when I return false from onsubmit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723381/why-does-my-html-form-still-submit-when-i-return-false-from-onsubmit)

Answer (score 1):

It would seem this.form.submit() is bypassing the the min/max checks even if you do it in the console (getting form by id  then calling submit). I don't think this has to do with your setup.

Try this approach

```
<form>
  <input type="number" id="endNo" name="endNo" placeholder="END" min="5" max="20" required> <!-- I assume it is required? -->
  <input type="button" id="fakeSubmit" name="name" value="REGISTER"     onclick="submitIfValid()"> <!-- fake submit -->
  <input type="submit" id="submitButton" style="visibility:hidden"> <!-- Actual submit -->
</form>

<script>
 function submitIfValid()
 {
    if(document.getElementById('endNo').value < document.getElementById('endNo').getAttribute("min") || document.getElementById('endNo').value > document.getElementById('endNo').getAttribute("max")) // Get the attributes dynamically and check
     {
       document.getElementById('submitButton').click(); // Simulate a standard click to show error
     }  
     else
     {
       document.getElementById('fakeSubmit').disabled = true; // Disabled it, we got our value
       document.getElementById('submitButton').click(); // Actual submission
     }

 }
</script>
```

Make sure you add your server side checks. NEVER trust jQuery or javascript

Note: If left blank, it would be < than the min

Note 2: If you are open minded towards jQuery, the form validation becomes a lot easier ($(formid).valid()) which makes it easier than my approach and in case of multiple fields to check. You can read about it [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid).

Answer (score 0):

You could change the input type from `submit` to `button`  to stop it from submitting right away.

```
 <input type="button" name="name" value="REGISTER" onclick="this.disabled='true';this.form.submit();" />
```

Comment: There really wan't any syntax error. While isolated, both cases work as expected. It is only when combined that the validation fails. Nonetheless, I did try out your solution and still it doesn't produce the desired result. The chrome notification appears briefly but the form submits anyway.

Comment: Setting the `.disabled` property to (boolean) `true` is *not* a JS error, it is correct and normal procedure; setting it to the string `"true"` is incorrect. Also, you don't need the `javascript:` label in an inline event handler.